# How can I make a deck class that has an attribute that is a list of card objects?

Tags: java, class, object, arraylist, extends

I have two classes, one is Card other is Deck, on Card I have two attributes Card(String name, Suit type) where Suit is a enum (`public enum Suit{SPADES, HEARTS, DIAMONDS, CLUBS;}`)

then I want to make an attribute `public List<Card> deck = new ArrayList<Card>();` on the Deck class:

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

public class Deck extends Card {
    public List<Card> deck = new ArrayList<Card>();
    
    public Deck() {
        this.deck.add(Card("two", Suit.CLUBS));
    }
    
}
```

But it keeps telling me `Implicit super constructor Carta() is undefined. Must explicitly invoke another constructor` on `public Deck` line and also `Create method Card(String, Suit)`

I have tried to put `Super();` inside the constructor and it's not working, it's probably because I am missing something, that is why I am here :)

My objective, like I said earlier is to have a **atribute List with all 52 Card cards of a daily deck**

Comment: `Deck extends Card` <- Why did you make Deck a SubClass of Card?  A deck is  not a more specific type of a card, so this extending makes little sense to me. Also: You neew to call constructors with the `new` keyword like `new Card(.....)`

Comment: `Deck` should hold a `Collection` of `Card`. Depending on your card type I would suggest a `Set`.  More over it might be useful to have `Deck` as an interface as there are many different card decks available, not all countries use a 52 card deck, for the same reason it might be worth considering how you model Card and Suit as not all Decks and countries use the same Suits some might use Cups, others Hearts etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you don't create a new object. You must write `new Card("two", Suit.CLUBS)` to create a new Card objekt.

And I think you don't need to extend the Card class. If you need it, the first line in the construktor must be `super();` to call the construktor of Card.

Answer (score 0):

So the only problem was that I was missing the new to instance the Card -.-
thanks